# How can I configure RSpec to run my model tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2

No matter what I do, the only tests that run with the `rake test` command are those in `spec/requests`. Naturally, I would like to run ***everything*** in the `spec` directory.

I thought getting the gem and installing RSpec would do it, but it seems with these testing libraries that the whole "convention over configuration" thing is turned on its head. There's a hell of a lot of configuration.

I simply want to run all of my tests. How can I do that?

Comment: Why not `rspec spec` ?

Comment: Have you tried just using `rspec spec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your Rakefile look like? You may need to add the following:

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new
```

Also, check that your spec's filenames all end in `_spec.rb`.

Comment: I was converting over from a failed attempt at Minitest, so all my stuff ended in _test. Thanks alot Andy!

Answer (score 1):

Just this will do:

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

This must be fired from root directory of application. Here `spec` is the directory.